# Как отцентрировать текст в c#

Tags: c#, центрирование

Пробую отцентрировать текст в онлайн компиляторе, но ничего не выходит. Прошу подсказать, что не так.

```
using System;
class program {
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    string centerText = "Случайный текст!";
    Console.Clear();
    int centerX = (Console.WindowWidth / 2) - (centerText.Length / 2);
    int centerY = (Console.WindowHeight / 2) - 1;
    Console.SetCursorPosition(centerX, centerY);
    Console.Write(centerText);
    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Upd. В Visual studio текст отцентрировался нормально, но на работе нет возможности использовать эту программу, поэтому использую онлайн компилятор. Прикладываю скриншот ошибки в компиляторе.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

П.С. прошу с пониманием отнестись к тому, что центрирование текста не делается именно в онлайн компиляторе, а не в visual studio, поэтому и задан этот вопрос.

Comment: Что такое "ничего не выходит"? Поясните подробнее в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Ничего не происходит - это означает, что текст по центру не отображается.

Comment: А как отображается?

Comment: @aepot, добавил скриншот ошибки в компиляторе. В Visual Studio всё работает "как надо", но нет возможности постоянно писать код в программе, поэтому используется онлайн компилятор. Хотелось бы понять, почему выходит такая ошибка.

Comment: Очевидно, что на сайте вывод в консоль перенаправлен, чтобы вывести его на страницу. Поэтому и задание координат курсора не работает. Полагаю, с этим ничего не поделать.

Comment: А выведите на печать, что у вас в `Console.WindowWidth` и `Console.WindowHeight` там получается. Что-то там видимо не то совсем и в результате либо отрицательное число у вас в итоге выходит в `centerX` или `centerY`, либо слишком большое.

Comment: В следующий раз вставляйте текст ошибки текстом.

Comment: @ВиталийПетров значит Alexander Petrov был прав, вывод перенаправлен, следовательно перед вами не полноценная консоль и фишка с центрированием текста работать не будет. Ответ я удалил, так как он бесполезен для вас. Пишите код в локальной консоли, к черту эти онлайн-компиляторы.

Comment: @aepot, понял Вас. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Alexander Petrov, спасибо за ответ!